# how can we minimize chances of getting ORA-14766: Unable to obtain a stable metadata snapshot

Tags: sql, oracle

During my development task, i am facing oracle issue - **"ORA-14766: Unable to obtain a stable metadata snapshot"**

I tried searching for many solution on google but observed that there is no specific solution available to resolve this issue.

How this issue generally occure:
Mostly whenwe have large amount of data as well as have CLOB columns as part of our source query then this issue occred if there is any partition changed/ drop orcreated on source tables.
due to this, current cursor session become invalidated and process is failing with ORA-14766.

As a temporary solution,
we have created one temp table that will store source query data and during execution of process, if any one tries to change/drop/create partition on source table then our process will not fail becasue process is referring temp table instead of actual source tables

Does anyone faced simillar kind of issue? it would be great if you provide some solutions that you tried to minimize chances of ORA-14766 oracle issue?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Why are people modifying partitions while your code is running?  Partitions generally implies a data warehouse which generally implies that data is being loaded only via an ETL process.  Is this a nightly load or are you loading throughout the day?  For a traditional nightly load, you're generally not running queries while the ETL process is running.  If this is an incremental load, why does it need to alter partitions?  You can generally create partitions well in advance overnight.  If there is a purge process that drops partitions, that seldom needs to be run during the day.

Comment: invalidation of the cursor in partitioned table? show table definiton

Comment: @JustinCave: We have different team referring to one large database and we have many process schedule in higher environment, if process is running for new id (primary key which is part of partition/subpartition) then process first create partition and then load data. Issue that i mentioned above, that process take 45hrs to execute end to end flow as data volumn is huge and during thsi 45hrs other schdule process are executed and creating partition on all available table that casue issue mentioned above. and we have only one script that used by all process to create partition on tables.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh: table definition is normal (like column, datatype and length) there is nothing additional mentioned. as we are working on huge data (7million) processing taking long time. to take control over process we have divided completed data into equal size of chunks (NTILE function) and process one chunk at a time instead whole data. Problem is for example - if process is processing chunk - 11 and parallely other schedule process run that create partition on source then cursor becaome invalid and while executin chunk 12 it will failed with issue mentioned above

Comment: Unless you're loading, say, 10 TB of data, 45 hours seems grossly excessive.  Almost certainly, someone needs to spend some time optimizing that process.  Is it possible to create the partitions in advance rather than creating them at load time?  Normally, you'd have a very quick process that runs, say, once a month, that creates all the partitions you'd need for the next month.